# Don't allow same answer in Google Form

Tags: google-forms

So I have a problem where I want to use **google form** for data collection for few different teams.

At google form the first question is to type in the item number (6 symbols) and there is no duplicates at all.

So if someone already submitted their form and that item was submitted that day. I don't want other team to go through items and waste their time on same items which was already submitted by other team.

Is it possible to get error saying "sorry, this item with this number was submitted today"? The item number (value) should be picked from google sheet specific column of that generated google form.

Answer (score 0):

There are two alternatives

1. Use Google Apps Script to update the question validation rule on form submit.
2. Instead of using a short answer question, use a dropdown question and use Google Apps Script to update the question options.

NOTE: Instead of writing yourself the script, you could use a Google Forms add-on

Related

- [Script error trying to populate form drop down menu from spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/51534/88163)
- [Adding a script to Google Forms to identify incorrect phone numbers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/70812/88163)